# Random number/sequence output

Tags: serial, c++, c

The program I'm trying to build is:

1. Type in 1st name, hit enter, type in 2nd name and then hit enter again.
2. Register those names from string input to char `naming` in `student` struct.
3. Print out the names in serial monitor.
4. Use those names in the main program.

The problem is I got randomize results whenever I typed in the names.

My target output:

```
Program Starts
Insert 2 students name:

First student: Adam     //When input -> Adam
Second student: Eve     //When input -> Eve
First student: John    //When input -> John
Second student: Amy    //When input -> Amy
//the sequences should repeat
```

...but what happened is the sequences of the names randomized. For example:

```
Program Starts
Insert 2 students name:

First student: Adam
First student: Eve
Second student: John
First student: Amy
//the sequences will keep randomizing
```

Can anyone point out what I've missed out?

The program:

```
typedef struct
    {
        char naming[20];         
    }student;

    student record[]{
      {""},
      {""},
    };

    String readString;
    String str=""; 

    // the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);    // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second
      while (!Serial);              // wait for Serial Monitor to open
      SerialUSB.println("Program Starts \n Insert 2 students name:");  // Title of sketch 
    }

    void loop() {
        namedata();
        mainprg();
    }

    void namedata() 
    {
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < sizeof(record)/sizeof(student); i++){
          while (Serial.available()) {
            char c = Serial.read();
            readString += c;
            readString.trim();
          }

          if (readString.length() >0) {
            str = readString;
            str.toCharArray(record[i].naming,20);
            if(i==0){
               Serial.print("First student: ");
            }else if(i==1){ 
               Serial.print("Second student: ");
            }
            Serial.println(record[i].naming);        
          }
            readString="";
        } 
    }

    void mainprg()
    {
      //main program using student`s name
    }
```

Additional infos:

1.Why use struct? Because I've more data to process/store for one "student" in my main program.
2.Currently using Arduino Yun Mini, Arduino 1.8.7

Thanks in advance!

Comment: change `++i` to `i++`

Comment: @Juraj Nope still the same, though I also tried `if(int i; i<2; i++)` to no avail...

Comment: your algorithm for reading the names is based on misunderstanding how Serial input works

Comment: @Juraj I would appreciate it if you can point me to any info on the topic

Comment: The problem, that Juraj mentioned, is that you seem to think, that all the data from one name input will arrive as a big chunk, so that the `while` loop will only exit, when a full name has been read. That is not the case. There might be pauses between arbitrary bytes in the stream, for example introduced from the OS of the PC. The while loop will often exit, before a full name is read. You can use the something like the readline function here: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino

Comment: @chrisl Thank you for the link. I (somewhat) understand now how `Serial.read` works, but I still cannot pause the loop until the second name input and register it into `record[i].naming`, thus the random sequences caused by random loop exits.

Comment: Why do you use `SerialUSB` in your setup function, but `Serial` in the rest of the code? I'm not sure, what happens on an Arduino with only one serial interface, when using `SerialUSB`, but on other boards (as I recall the Due for example) These two are complete different interfaces. Though I don't see, how you can get this randomized order due to this.

Comment: @chrisl About the `SerialUSB`, you are right; its the same thing as [`Serial`](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=402933.0).  As for the randomized order, I wonder that myself  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this is not elegant by any means, for now this is what I've came out with:

```
typedef struct
{
  char naming[20];
} student;

student record[] {
  {""},
  {""},
};

int a = 0;

char buf[20];

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);    // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second
  while (!Serial);              // wait for Serial Monitor to open
  Serial.println("Program Starts \n Insert 2 students name:");  // Title of sketch
}

void loop() {
  if (readline(Serial.read(), buf, 20) > 0) {
    if (a == 0) {
      Serial.print("First student: ");
      strncpy(record[a].naming, buf, 20);
      Serial.println(record[a].naming);
      a = 1;
    }
    else if ( a == 1) {
      Serial.print("Second student: ");
      strncpy(record[a].naming, buf, 20);
      Serial.println(record[a].naming);
    }

  }
}

int readline(int readch, char *buffer, int len) {
  static int pos = 0;
  int rpos;

  if (readch > 0) {
    switch (readch) {
      case '\r': // Ignore CR
        break;
      case '\n': // Return on new-line
        rpos = pos;
        pos = 0;  // Reset position index ready for next time
        return rpos;
      default:
        if (pos < len - 1) {
          buffer[pos++] = readch;
          buffer[pos] = 0;
        }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Basically by using `int a`, the program decides the sequences of the name. Although it will not repeat the sequence after the 2nd input (ie 1st>2nd>1st>2nd), at least the sequence is not randomize anymore.

Btw thanks for the tips @chrisl!